# Using Uber, Amazon apps in public networks

Tags: sensitive-data-exposure

Everybody knows that one should not enter sensitive data in public wifi networks. Checking bank account using bar's wifi is not the best idea.

But what about applications that also use sensitive data? For example, I come to new country, connect to airport wifi (internet roaming is usually not the cheapest one) open Uber application on my android and look for a taxi. Normally, data about my credit card is already saved at Uber's servers and I transfer only some ID of payment type. I also hope that Uber use https encryption of my data of taxi search.

There are also some scenarios like buying something, for example, at Amazon and using for payment saved credit card.

I find this dangerous depending on the application. I hope that popular applications like Uber, Amazon, etc. think a bit about security and never transfer card details after it is saved one time on their servers. So they are safe to use even with sensitive data in public networks.
But I have doubts about this. Do you think the same as me? Maybe I loose something.

Comment: The credit card info is a PCI compliance issue. The other parameters however, like the taxi you're searching for, or the item you're searching for on Amazon. That probably comes down to each company itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS has been designed to provide confidentiality and integrity of communication across untrusted networks. While I would agree that I would avoid doing banking on public networks if you can avoid it, so long as you're not seeing certificate errors while doing it (which means you're traffic is being intercepted) I would say you're *probably* okay and don't have too much to worry about.

Now I will qualify that with that fact there are appliances and vendors (such as Symantec / BlueCoat) that could intercept your traffic without you seeing any errors as Symantec is a trusted CA. With that said these appliances are very expensive and not likely to be deployed in smaller "wifi" hotspots.

In the instance where your Credit Card is saved on file prior, those details are stored on their end and do not cross the wire back to your device when processing transactions. The application, such as Uber or Amazon will interact with the credit card processor to process the transaction and not your phone so that shouldn't be a concern for you. Your concern should be the transmission of your credentials over untrusted networks, but as mentioned above so long as you don't see certificate errors I would imagine you're okay.